# Generate tree output from specific/general XML file in Bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, xml

I am trying to generate a tree from an XML file in Bash.

This is a part of the XML file:

```xml
<menu name="main_menu" display="Main Menu">
  <application name="load_profiles" display="Load Profile"/>
  <application name="save_profiles" display="Save Profile"/>
  <application name="remove_profiles" display="Delete Profile"/>
</menu>
```

I have tried to use CAT and GREP and AWK:

```
cat menu.xml | grep menu\ name | awk -v FS="(display=\"|\" help)" '{print $2}' > menulist.txt
```

I have first GREPed using the lines that have "Menu Name" and then printed the Tests between 'display="' and '" help' and came out with this output:

```
Main Menu">
Broadband
Load and Save Profiles
xDSL Interface
```

But what I want is to Grep all the lines that have "Menu Name", "parameter type", "application name" and "value id" and print their display name in a tree like output. I am not sure how I can Grep multiple values from multiple lines and print a specific string from it.

Then I have seen that it is comparatively easier to do this with a XML parser tool. So I have tried with XMLStarlet:

```
xmlstarlet el menu.xml | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{print "digraph{"}{print $(NF-1)" -> "$NF}END{print"}"}' > menumenutxt.txt
```

Using this command I have found the following output:

```
menu -> menu
menu -> onenter
menu -> menu
menu -> application
menu -> application
menu -> application
menu -> parameter
parameter -> value
parameter -> value
```

Which definitely looks better and closer to what I want. But it's not printing the display name.

What I am trying to print is something like this:

```
 Main Menu -> 
           -> Broadband 
                        -> Load and Save Profiles
                                                  -> Load Profile
                                                  -> Save Profile
                                                  -> Delete Profile
```

Or the following:

```
Main Menu 
-> Broadband 
--> Load and Save Profiles
---> Load Profile
---> Save Profile
---> Delete Profile
```

My aim to get an output as close to it as possible. Can anyone suggest me how I should proceed with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adapting one of the examples from [the xmlstarlet docs](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' \
    -i '@display' \
        -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' \
            -i '(position()=last())' \
                -o '-> ' -v '@display' -b \
            -o $'\t' -b \
        -n foo.xml
```

The example is:

> Print structure of XML element using xml sel (advanced XPath
>   expressions and xml sel command usage)
>
> ```
> xml sel -T -t -m '//*' \
> -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -v 'name()' -i 'not(position()=last())' -o . -b -b -n \
> xml/structure.xml
> ```
>
> Result Output:
>
> ```
> a1
> a1.a11
> a1.a11.a111
> a1.a11.a111.a1111
> a1.a11.a112
> a1.a11.a112.a1121
> a1.a12
> a1.a13
> a1.a13.a131
> ```

From here, the things we need to modify are:

- print the `display` attribute instead of the `name`, so `@display` instead of `name()`
- print it only for the last element. We already have the test for printing `.` for all but the last element, so it's easy to invert that.
- print tabs to indent (we can do it after every element, it will just leave trailing, invisible tab), so just `-o $'\t'`. `$'\t'` in bash will get you a tab character.
- print only for elements which have the `display` attribute, so `-i '@display'`

I have indented the command above to make the flow clearer.

The output I get:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' -i '@display' -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' -i '(position()=last())' -o '-> ' -v '@display' -b -o $'\t' -b -n foo.xml
-> English
    -> Main Menu
        -> Broadband
            -> Load and Save Profiles
                -> Load Profile
                -> Save Profile
                -> Delete Profile
            -> Interface
                -> xDSL
                -> SFP
                -> Ethernet
                -> SHDSL
            -> xDSL Interface
                -> xDSL Mode
                    -> Annex A/M
                    -> Annex B/J
                -> MAC Address
                    -> MAC Address
                -> Vectoring Mode
                    -> Disabled
                    -> Enabled
                    -> Friendly
                -> G.FAST
                    -> Disabled
                    -> Enabled
```

---

After thinking a bit, the following is simpler:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' \
    -i '@display' \
        -m 'ancestor::*' \
            -o $'\t' -b \
        -o '-> ' -v '@display' -n foo.xml
```

Using `ancestor::*` instead of `ancestor-or-self::*` makes printing the tabs correctly easier, and eliminates the extra test for last element.

Similar output, but without trailing tabs:

```
-> English
    -> Main Menu
        -> Broadband
            -> Load and Save Profiles
                -> Load Profile
                -> Save Profile
                -> Delete Profile
            -> Interface
                -> xDSL
                -> SFP
                -> Ethernet
                -> SHDSL
            -> xDSL Interface
                -> xDSL Mode
                    -> Annex A/M
                    -> Annex B/J
                -> MAC Address
                    -> MAC Address
                -> Vectoring Mode
                    -> Disabled
                    -> Enabled
                    -> Friendly
                -> G.FAST
                    -> Disabled
                    -> Enabled
```

Comment: Hi Muru, I have a question. If I want to add a counter instead of tab how should I do that? I tried adding a counter instead of tab here:  `-o $'\t' -b` but it just appends the value(as it should), and I can't figure out how I should print the number of tabs instead of tabs.

Comment: @Russo I'm sure `xmlstarlet` probably has some way of doing this, but for now, maybe use `awk` to process the output: `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '//*' -i '@display' -m 'ancestor::*' -o $'\t' -b -o '-> ' -v '@display' -n foo.xml | awk -F '\t' '{print NF,$NF}'`

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. It's not mandatory that I use xmlstarlet. Thank you.

Comment: @ Muru, very cool!!

Comment: If you get `Attempt to load network entity`, [add `--net`](https://sourceforge.net/p/xmlstar/discussion/226076/thread/59b1ba60/#e087) after the subcommand

Answer (score 0):

(If not already installed, install xidel)

```
xidel ex.xml  \
  -e '//@display/concat(substring("------",1,count(ancestor::*)),">",.)'
```

- `substring("------",1,n)` is a dirty way of building a string with n "-"